# Diamagnetic effects in matter

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, electromagnetic-induction

According to my physics book, all materials could manifest diamagnetic effects (it is a consequence of Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction). However due to the presence of intrinsic magnetic moments of molecules, the effects of diamagnetism are weak.
Anyway I am not sure why.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I want to know how it is possible that the presence of a n intrinsic magnetic moment can cancel the diamagnetic effects

Comment: In absence of any external magnetic field, individual intrinsic magnetic dipole moment of each atom/molecule is "zero". But when you introduce an external field, the substance develops a net weak magnetic moment "opposite" to the applied field. So it is infact the cause of diamagnetism( and not that it cancel the diamagnetic effects). It would be better if you quote the exact words what your Physics book claims.

Comment: By the way, if you are asking why the diamagnetic effects are weaker as compared to paramagnetic and ferromagnetic effects:-     1. In diamagnetic materials, the atoms have 0 moment initially. So you would need a good amount of external field to create a good nice effect.    2. Paramagnetic materials, atoms already possess some dipole moment. It is just that all get cancelled up when no external field present. So u would need to do a little to align them in the same direction.          3. In ferromagnetic materials, it's even easier since the individual dipole moments are grouped into domains.

Comment: I am not talking about diamagnetic materials. I am referring to a class of materials which have weak effects due to an applied magnetic field.